# How to reinstall rpm package?

Tags: package, rpm, reinstall

I have installed a package from *.rpm* file and it is stored in */opt*.

After some configuration I found that I need to reinstall the software.  So I deleted the directory and attempted to reinstall the file with `rpm -i XXX.rpm`.  But it tells me that `package xxx is already installed`.

How can I reinstall it?

Comment: Learn from this lesson :) use `rpm(8)` to uninstall packages in the future. Get friendly with the `--force` options...

Comment: I learnt. haha :D..thanks! BTW could you tell me the command. is it rpm --force XXX.rpm? it doesn't seem working

Comment: @Newbie You got to tell the program *what* you want to force. `--force` gets applied additionally.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try: `rpm -iv --replacepkgs <packagefile>`.

More details [are in the book](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-install-additional-options.html).

Comment: This doesn't uninstall files from old package. If files different they will be dangling from old package.

Comment: @midenok I don't exactly understand what you're saying but I suspect that you've got a different situation than the one raised a dozen years ago by the original poster. It would probably be best to start a new question with full details of your situation so people with current knowledge and understanding can give you the best available answer. Thanks.

Comment: No, thanks. If you don't understand, please don't disturb. Probably you cannot understand since you did the wrong answer, just leave that be.

Comment: The correct answer as of now is `-i --reinstall`, see below (this answer as of 2011 was anyway wrong).

Answer (score 20):

You could also hit:

```
rpm -ivh --force [yourpackage.rpm]
```

which safely overwrites the old installed package with the desired new package.
Furthermore, if you wish to install and upgrade simultaneously, then this next option:

```
rpm -Uvh [yourpackage.rpm]
```

will enable you to install including any upgrade simultaneously.

Another extra tip: You may face an error situation where an upgrade depends on another which in turn depends on another and inturn also depend on the one you want to install thus causing a "**dependency upgrade loop**". To avoid that hit:

```
rpm -Uvh --nodeps [yourpackage.rpm].
```

Comment: rpm -ivh --force [yourpackage.rpm] is the best solution for reinstalling an RPM package

Comment: Telling the OP who could not install a package because it had already been installed to use `--force` instead of `--replacepkgs` (as suggested in the already accepted answer) is wrong because `--force` *(...) adds --replacepkgs and --replacefiles to the command.* (http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-install-additional-options.html) so using it might lead to overwriting files installed as part of unrelated package. Using `--replacepkgs` is safer and should be enough in this situation.

Answer (score 11):

Starting with version 4.12.0 there's `--reinstall` option.

From [RPM 4.12.0 Release Notes](http://rpm.org/wiki/Releases/4.12.0):

> New `--reinstall` mode which can handle changing file policies
>   ([RhBug:966715](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=966715))

From `man rpm`:

> `rpm {--reinstall} [install-options] PACKAGE_FILE ...`
>
> This reinstalls a previously installed package.

Answer (score 1):

You got to uninstall the software's rpm:

```
rpm -e XXX.rpm
```

Then install it :

```
rpm -i XXX.rpm
```

Next time whenever you are not sure about the software being already there on the machine, always check using:

```
rpm -qa |grep XXX
```

where XXX is the software name or part of the name.
This will give you the version already present on the machine.